# How to pass data in a php,html multi tabbed form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, codeigniter

How to pass data in a php,html multi tabbed form. from one tab to another... like first tab ask user to enter detailed of a product when he press submit button 2nd tab open and where user can upload pictures to a directory. And most important i am using codeigniter.. please help me

Comment: upload your code friend

Comment: Go through this https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/

Comment: This cant helped me. I have read almost complete guide. If you know that specific portion related to my question please tell me

Comment: upload us to see your try

Comment: you have to use ajax to achieve this

Comment: could you give any link as example.

Comment: Are you trying to A) save all of the tabbed form data at once or are you  B) trying to save each individual tab's data as it's own form?

Comment: @cro I want to do (A).

Answer (score 1):

When you press submit it does a full request? The tabs content are already loaded in the page, but hidden by javascript. 
If you do a full request, you need to send data back to the response and fill the value attribute of the tags you want to pass data to, and if you are using javascript to do that, you can easily set the values you need just knowing the html id attribute of the fields you want to set data to.
If you upload some code, we can give you a more concrete answer.

Comment: how can i upload my code. bcz it shows error that my message is too long. As i am newbie at stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so what you should do is wrap your form around all of your tabs. When they need to switch tabs, don't submit what they have so far, just write some javascript that will open the next tab for them on a button click. Let them submit the entire form only at the last tab.